# Angular 1.x Directive With A Template

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create an angular directive for forming sentences. The goal is to take a list and iterate through them as necessary. The result of the directive would be something like:

> shoes, pants and socks

**or**

> shoes, pants and +5 more

I have the basic directive setup to work with a array of strings - but I'd like to customize it to allow custom templates for each sentence element (i.e. hyperlinks, styling, etc). That is:

```
<sentence values="article in articles">
<strong>{{article.title}}</strong> by <span>{{article.author}}</span>
</sentence>
```

The HTML the user sees in the browser needs to be something like:

```
$scope.articles = [
  { title: '...', author: '...'},
  { title: '...', author: '...'},
  ...
]

<span><strong>ABC</strong> by <span>123</span></span>
<span>, </span>
<span><strong>DEF</strong> by <span>456</span></span>
<span>and</span>
<span>+5 more</span>
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with `transclude` but cannot figure out the API. I've also experimented with using `ng-repeat` instead of the directive template but wasn't able to find a solution.

Comment: you can use ng-repeat="article in articles", and it will create the necessary "sentence" tags.

Comment: I understand I can use `ng-repeat` to iterate through all tags. My goal though is to generate a sentence (i.e. with the "," and "and") that truanctes if the sentence if it is longer than three by showing the "+5 more". I know how to build a one off version - but want to be able to reusable directive so I can use it in multiple areas of the app. Or am I missing something?

Comment: What you are looking for sounds to me more like a filter

Comment: interesting... you can use a function to generate the list... a bit example: "article in queryResolver('shoes, pants and socks')... and then, that function returns the list

Comment: @MilitelloVinx not clear on how a filter helps in this case (I also need to generate the separators).

Comment: I dont write about filter... I suggest a function only.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo Whoops - also not clear. How does a function help with?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, so if this is the case I am sorry.  The thing is that with a filter, you can change the text that you are going to show.
I have created a little [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/a5HvLReWIKriufqNFTxL) to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work where `maxArticles` is a number defined on your scope

```
<sentence values="article in articles | limitTo: maxArticles">
    <strong>{{article.title}}</strong> by <span>{{article.author}}</span>
    <span ng-if="$index < maxArticles - 2">, </span>
    <span ng-if="$index === articles.length - 1 && articles.length <= maxArticles">and</span>
</sentence>
<span ng-if="articles.length > maxArticles">
    and +{{articles.length - maxArticles}} more.
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating *AND* providing dynamic content is a common use for a custom directive with the `compile` function + the `$compile` service. Watch out: essentially you are repeating the functionality of `ng-repeat`, you may want to consider alternatives.

E.g. instead of the `articles` list, use another one (perhaps named `articlesLimited`). The new list is constructed dynamically and contains the first elements from `articles`. A flag (e.g. `hasMore`) indicates whether the original `articles` has more elements, simply as: `$scope.hasMore = articles.length > 5`. You use the `hasMore` flag to show/hide the "+N more" message.

For what it's worth however, below is an implementation of the `sentence` directive. See the comment for weak points!

```
app.directive('sentence', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  var RE = /^([a-z_0-9\$]+)\s+in\s([a-z_0-9\$]+)$/i, ONLY_WHITESPACE = /^\s*$/;

  function extractTrimmedContent(tElem) {
    var result = tElem.contents();
    while( result[0].nodeType === 3 && ONLY_WHITESPACE.test(result[0].textContent) ) {
      result.splice(0, 1);
    }
    while( result[result.length-1].nodeType === 3 && ONLY_WHITESPACE.test(result[result.length-1].textContent) ) {
      result.length = result.length - 1;
    }
    return result;
  }

  function extractIterationMeta(tAttrs) {
    var result = RE.exec(tAttrs.values);
    if( !result ) {
      throw new Error('malformed values expression, use "itervar in list": ', tAttrs.values);
    }
    var cutoff = parseInt(tAttrs.cutoff || '5');
    if( isNaN(cutoff) ) {
      throw new Error('malformed cutoff: ' + tAttrs.cutoff);
    }
    return {
      varName: result[1],
      list: result[2],
      cutoff: cutoff
    };
  }

  return {
    scope: true, // investigate isolated scope too...
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
      var iterationMeta = extractIterationMeta(tAttrs);

      var content = $compile(extractTrimmedContent(tElem));
      tElem.empty();

      return function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var scopes = [];
        scope.$watchCollection(
          function() {
            // this is (IMO) the only legit usage of scope.$parent:
            // evaluating an expression we know is meant to run in our parent
            return scope.$parent.$eval(iterationMeta.list);
          },
          function(newval, oldval) {
            var i, item, childScope;

            // this needs OPTIMIZING, the way ng-repeat does it (identities, track by); omitting for brevity
            // if however the lists are not going to change, it is OK as it is
            scopes.forEach(function(s) {
              s.$destroy();
            });
            scopes.length = 0;
            elem.empty();

            for( i=0; i < newval.length && i < iterationMeta.cutoff; i++ ) {
              childScope = scope.$new(false, scope);
              childScope[iterationMeta.varName] = newval[i];
              scopes.push(childScope);
              content(childScope, function(clonedElement) {
                if( i > 0 ) {
                  elem.append('<span class="sentence-sep">, </span>');
                }
                elem.append(clonedElement);
              });
            }

            if( newval.length > iterationMeta.cutoff ) {
              // this too can be parametric, leaving for another time ;)
              elem.append('<span class="sentence-more"> +' + (newval.length - iterationMeta.cutoff) + ' more</span>');
            }
          }
        );
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aza6u64p/

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem. Transclude is used to wrap elements but when using transclude you don't have access to the directive scope, only to the scope of where the directive is being used:

[AnglularJS: Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

> What does this transclude option do, exactly? transclude makes the contents of a directive with this option have access to the scope outside of the directive rather than inside.

So a solution is to create another component to inject the template's scope inside the directive, like this:

```
.directive('myList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: { items: '=' },
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items" inject></div>'
  };
})

.directive('inject', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, controller, $transclude) {
      $transclude($scope, function(clone) {
        $element.empty();
        $element.append(clone);
      });
    }
  };
})

<my-list items="articles">
    <strong>{{item.title}}</strong> by <span>{{item.author}}</span>
</my-list>
```

This was taken from this discussion: [#7874](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7874)

And I made a [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TVav67ICPlttPU2xAiRP?p=preview).

Comment: I didn't include in the solution the code to process the size of the list and include the "+5 more", but it is the easy part.